# How to animate the model instance transparency in libgdx 3d API?

Tags: 3d, libgdx

I use the libGDX 3D API in a game. I want to gradually fade out a 3d model instance over time.

A saw it is possible to animate model instance position, scale or rotation, but I didn't found a way to animate transparency.

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Comment: Here's an example: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/g3d/MaterialTest.java